# Resuming after suspend problem ,Freezing and multible errors on wakeup

Tags: suspend, 19.10, dmesg

After i lay down my laptop screen and open it again i get multiple error messages.
what i got from `dmesg` ...

```
[   80.203323] Freezing of tasks failed after 20.005 seconds (1 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0):
[  149.775578] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: failed to reset PPM!
[  149.775590] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: PPM init failed (-110)
[  189.031585] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: PPM NOT RESPONDING
[  413.550818] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
[  412.780005] PM: dpm_run_callback(): ucsi_ccg_resume+0x0/0x20 [ucsi_ccg] returns -110
[  412.780007] PM: Device 0-0008 failed to resume: error -110
```

Answer (score 12):

In my case, this looks like a problem with the 5.3 kernel not handling the nvidia gpu usb-c driver properly. See [here on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1850238) for a detailed and well written description of the bug. I was having the same problem as that person (seeing a 50 second hang on resume). On that page, a temporary solution is given, namely to 'blacklist ucsi_ccg'. When I implemented that fix, my hang on resume went away and I saw no errors.

My steps to fix...

1. Ran `ls /etc/modprobe.d` and found a catchall `blacklist.conf` file that looked like it might be a good spot to add my new blacklist line.
2. Ran `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and add a line `blacklist ucsi_ccg` to the bottom of the file. Save file and exit nano.
3. Reboot, then suspend my machine to test the fix. When I open the lid, the machine immediately starts back up with no errors.

Note that since that driver is blacklisted, you might lose your ability to use the usb-c port on your machine, but I wasn't using mine so it wasn't a big deal for me. The trick for me will be to remember in 6 months why my usb-c port doesn't work when I plug something into it. :)

Comment: Is there any solution to this that doesn't brick the USB-C port?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I upgraded debian 9 to debian 10 buster. This happens when I plugged something in my USB 3.0 port when the suspends coming up it freezes completely all my USB ports including keyboard and mouse. My solution was to not plug anything in the USB 3.0 ports, only on 2.0. I am using kernel 5.4 and nvidia driver but it seems a problem from the xhci firmware. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the delayed suspend and awake with  "Device 0-0008 failed to resume" problem.   Adding the blacklist above helped, and while that may disable a USB-C port on the graphics card (not available on my 2060 Super), the USB-C port connected directly to the motherboard remains functional.