# Error on resume from suspend system

Tags: suspend, 19.10, bios, acpi, iwlwifi

When I suspend my system, be it by closing the lid or by pressing the power button, the system has problems on resuming. It stays stuck in a black screen with error messages and freezes for a long time before it finally resumes. For comparison, shutting down and turning on again the system is 10 times quicker.

Which error messages are shown is not very consistent but they are always permutations of the same errors. Here I suspended the system 4 times in a row so i got 4 times the same kind of error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDtie.jpg

Here I suspended just one time and I also got an error ACPI message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gStqi.jpg

Some of the errors:

- `ACPI Error: No installed handler for fixed event - PowerButton`
- `iwlwifi (some_numbers): BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS`
- `PM: Device 0-0008 failed to resume: Error -110`

iwlwifi seems to be related to wifi, but my wifi is working fine, I don't know why it is showing an error. Also, how can I find out what is the device 0-0008?

System info dump:

- Ubuntu 19.10
- CPU: i7-9750HF
- GPU: Nvidia RTX 2060
- Screen: 1920x1080, 300 nits, 144 Hz
- Laptop: Lenovo Legion Y540 - 15IRH
- Model name: 81SX
- 16Gb of RAM, 1Tb HDD, 500Gb SSD
- BIOS version: BHCN36WW

Please let me know if there is any other information that I can supply that could help

---

edit: I found this question that sheds some light on the matter:[Resuming after suspend problem ,Freezing and multible errors on wakeup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193340/resuming-after-suspend-problem-freezing-and-multible-errors-on-wakeup)

It may be the same issue but in my case I also have the ACPI error.
Besides, I don't understand what is going on and would apreciate an explanation. I have an acpi error, an error with the wifi driver and the real culprit is an Usb-C port on the gpu? 
I would also like to keep my usb-c port working, changing kernel or distro could solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging around I think I found a better solution than blacklisting `ucsi_ccg`.

I'm not sure why, but moving up from kernel 5.3 to **kernel 5.4** fixed the issue and the USB-C port seems to be working as well. I don't get any more error messages, it takes a little bit more than 30 seconds to wake up from suspend which is not the fastest thing ever but I don't know if it should be faster or this is just how it is. Certainly faster than before and no more errors.