# ~30 second delay when waking from suspend - Device 0-0008 failed to resume: error -110

Tags: 18.04, kernel, suspend, resume

I have a freshy-installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with a 5.3 Linux kernel.

Whenever I wake my computer from suspend, I'm greeted with a black screen with error messages. After about ~30 seconds, it goes away on its own and resumes waking normally.

[image: Photograph of error message on startup]

```
PM: dpm_run_callback(): ucsi_ccg_resume()+0x0/0x20 [ucsi_ccg] returns -110
PM: Device 0-0008 failed to resume: error -110
```

Every iteration of suspending and waking appends two of those lines to the end. Upon a full reboot of the computer, this 'error log' is wiped clean, but the problem persists and new messages are generated when suspending and waking again.

All in all it's possible to live with the issue (30 seconds isn't *that* long), but it's still kind of annoying.

EDIT:

```
sudo blkid
```

outputs:

```
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1: PTUUID="7d4970fc-9b94-4cdc-a671-427c0e35bc89" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL="ESP" UUID="C6D9-DDCB" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="9900e554-5c05-4da5-9b09-b149c7c73dd0"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="84c5f04a-96ec-4a44-839a-d9c1ce188820"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: LABEL="Acer" UUID="E0D0DCFDD0DCDABC" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="da0723f4-ac1d-47e6-be06-dcf0a4e0c645"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: LABEL="Recovery" UUID="CA44DFE244DFCF77" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="92fd1eb9-a3ee-484f-b09c-a90c26462f86"
/dev/nvme0n1p5: UUID="c19f5167-969c-4094-9056-fb5f6ae530a7" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="e5b49d92-c817-4b1d-aea5-9da6b75b4bf9"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Data" UUID="36A2E49BA2E460BB" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="61413dde-8ec0-48c8-a216-4d15fce46eb0"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
```

======================================================================

```
cat /etc/fstab
```

outputs:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=c19f5167-969c-4094-9056-fb5f6ae530a7 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=C6D9-DDCB  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

======================================================================

```
cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
```

outputs:

```
cat: /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume: No such file or directory
```

======================================================================

FURTHER EDIT:

```
free -h
```

outputs:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        3.8G        852M        424M         10G         10G
Swap:          2.0G          0B        2.0G
```

======================================================================

```
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
```

outputs:

```
V1.23
```

======================================================================

Computer is an Acer Nitro AN715-51. The processor is an Intel i7-9750H and the graphics card is an Nvidia GeForce GTX 1660Ti. It has three USB ports - one of these is a type C (those are the blue ones, right?), but I'm not currently using that for anything. I'm only using the other two: I have an optical mouse plugged into one USB port and a Tritton wireless headset in another (I don't think the headset can be related to the problem though - I've already tried unplugging it and rebooting without it, and the problem persisted).

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`.

Comment: I've added the information you asked for. `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` seems to be entirely absent. Is that unusual?

Comment: That all looks fine. The resume file isn't there sometimes. Show me `free -h` and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, and tell me the exact make/model # of your computer.

Comment: Do you have any USB-C devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a bug.

*"I'm experiencing a 50-second hang each time I resume from a "deep" (suspend-to-RAM) sleep.
It happens with the newer kernel (5.3 series; I'm currently running the version from eoan-proposed), but not with the version from the Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (uname says "5.0.0-31-generic #33~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP")."*

Try this...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/resume.conf` or `sudo pico /etc/modprobe.d/resume.conf`

Add the following line...

```
blacklist ucsi_ccg
```

Save the file and quit the editor.

`reboot`

Try suspend/resume.

**Note**: this blacklist will disable any USB-C ports on the Nvidia video card

**Source**: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1850238

**Source**: [Resuming after suspend problem ,Freezing and multible errors on wakeup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193340/resuming-after-suspend-problem-freezing-and-multible-errors-on-wakeup)

**Update #1:**

Your BIOS is slightly out of date. You have version 1.23, and the current version is 1.27, and can be downloaded from [here](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/7997?b=1).

Comment: Your solution resolved everything, thank you very much! I haven't gotten around to updating the BIOS yet, though - how necessary is that (I mean, evidently not strictly necessary to resolve this particular problem, but in general)?

Comment: @Drubbels Keeping the BIOS up to date is very important, especially because of all of the new security updates to keep the hackers out. It might even have an effect on your original problem.